# Angular 9 | Facebook share button not displaying image

Tags: angular, facebook-sharer

I have an Angular 9 SSR application - http://www.dosgamesworld.com/

In every page I have a Share Facebook button.

The issue i'm experience is that the `og:image` is not recognized correctly by Facebook for most of the pages.

All the images in the application are 320px X 200px.

Also the `meta` looks correct for all pages.

For this page it does work well - http://www.dosgamesworld.com/game/alleycat

```
     <meta property="fb:app_id" content="1596858517136240">
    <meta property="og:url" content="http://www.dosgamesworld.com/game/alleycat">
    <meta property="og:type" content="website">
    <meta property="og:title" content="DOS Games World - Alley Cat">
    <meta property="og:description" content="Alley Cat is a single player platform game. The player has to assume the role of a cat, which is outside of a house and has to go through a certain track, near ">
    <meta property="og:image" content="http://www.dosgamesworld.com/assets/images/alleycat.png">
  <meta property="og:image:type" content="image/png">
  <meta property="og:image:width" content="320">
  <meta property="og:image:height" content="200">
```

[image]

**BUT**, for other pages it does not work: for example http://www.dosgamesworld.com/game/pop

(`meta` looks correct, but the actual share is missing the photo)

```
  <meta property="fb:app_id" content="1596858517136240">
    <meta property="og:url" content="http://www.dosgamesworld.com/game/pop">
    <meta property="og:type" content="website">
    <meta property="og:title" content="DOS Games World - Prince of Persia">
    <meta property="og:description" content="Prince of Persia is one of the most famous and entertaining games of all time. The game is a fantasy cinematic platformer, which takes place in Ancient Persia. ">
    <meta property="og:image" content="http://www.dosgamesworld.com/assets/images/pop.png">
  <meta property="og:image:type" content="image/png">
  <meta property="og:image:width" content="320">
  <meta property="og:image:height" content="200">
```

[image]

When I look into the facebook developer tools i see the following error: `Provided og:image URL, http://www.dosgamesworld.com/assets/images/pop.png was not valid because it did not meet the minimum size constraint of 200px by 200px.`

Comment: look for my answer below and vote please if it works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahh got it, look carefully. Open the pop image url in browser. Its name is pop.png but its actually an jpeg image

**Change Meta of pop from**

```
<meta property="og:image:type" content="image/png">
```

**To**

```
<meta property="og:image:type" content="image/jpg"> or <meta property="og:image:type" content="image/jpeg">
```

**OR**

Change pop image to actual png.

Comment: Thx i've re-upload the pop image as `png` again.
How did you see that the `png` was not real `png`?

Comment: I opened png url in browser with pop.png it was showing its type as jpeg :D

Comment: But where did you see the type exactly? i want to understand to avoid this mistake in the future :)
can you add a screenshot? (note that `pop` was fixed so you can do on a different game)